# Ingresar datos en una tabla HTML usando JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formularios, vscode

Hola soy nuevo en HTML y necesito realizar el siguiente ejercicio: dado el siguiente codigo necesito implementar javascript para poder ir añadiendo los datos a la tabla, además cuando se le añada uno se podrá eliminar, por ultimo se debe ir contando el numero de registros

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Laboratorio 1
 </title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="insertar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <p>
   <label>Entre su Nombre:</label> <br>  
   <input id="nombre" type="text" value="Nombre..."><br> 
  </p>
  <p>
   <label>Entre su Apellido:</label> <br> 
   <input id="apellido" type="text" value="Apellido..."><br> 
  </p>
  <p>
   <label>Entre su C&eacute;dula:</label> <br>  
   <input id="cedula" type="text" value="CI..."> <br>
  </p>
  <button id="adicionar" type="button">Adicionar a la tabla</button>
</form>

<p>Elementos en la Tabla: <div id="adicionados">0</div></p>
<table border="1"> 
 <tr>
  <th>Nobmre</th>
  <th>Apellidos</th>
  <th>C&eacute;dula</th>
  <th>Eliminar</th>
  
 </tr> 
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#adicionar').click(funtion(){
  entro
  agregar();
 });
});
var cont=0;
function agregar(){
var fila='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td>'+cont+'</td><td>texto por defecto/td><td></td></tr>';
$('#adicionados').append(fila);
}
```

Comment: Debes mostrar tus avances para poderte ayudar con tus dudas asi funciona el sitio. Bienvenido

Comment: Ya añadi por favor espero su amable ayuda..gracias

Answer (score 10):

Aqui esta lo buscas, espero hacerte ayudado, si tienes dudas comenta, esta comentado para que estudies el codigo

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
//obtenemos el valor de los input

$('#adicionar').click(function() {
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
  var cedula = document.getElementById("cedula").value;
  var i = 1; //contador para asignar id al boton que borrara la fila
  var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' + nombre + '</td><td>' + apellido + '</td><td>' + cedula + '</td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila

  i++;

  $('#mytable tr:first').after(fila);
    $("#adicionados").text(""); //esta instruccion limpia el div adicioandos para que no se vayan acumulando
    var nFilas = $("#mytable tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
    //le resto 1 para no contar la fila del header
    document.getElementById("apellido").value ="";
    document.getElementById("cedula").value = "";
    document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
    document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
  });
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    //cuando da click obtenemos el id del boton
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove(); //borra la fila
    //limpia el para que vuelva a contar las filas de la tabla
    $("#adicionados").text("");
    var nFilas = $("#mytable tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
   <div class="form-group">
    <p>
      <label>Entre su Nombre:</label> <br>
      <input id="nombre" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre..."><br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Entre su Apellido:</label> <br>
      <input id="apellido" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Apellido..."><br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Entre su C&eacute;dula:</label> <br>
      <input id="cedula" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Cedúla"> <br>
    </p>
    <button id="adicionar" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Adicionar a la tabla</button>
  </div>
</form>

<p>Elementos en la Tabla:
  <div id="adicionados"></div>
</p>
<table  id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
  <tr>
    <th>Nobmre</th>
    <th>Apellidos</th>
    <th>C&eacute;dula</th>
    <th>Eliminar</th>

  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Me seria de mucha ayuda y de ante mano te quedo muy agradecido.

Comment: Gracias Luis Fernado, una consulta como le llamo dentro del html al js que es otro archivo, disculpa tanta molestia.

Comment: Luis Fernando, por favor si me puedes ayudar al momento de guardar los datos, se crea las filas y el boton de eliminar pero no se pueden visualizar los datos en la tabla.

Comment: @V.Rocha ya lo edite, echale un ojo al codigo ahora, ya funciona. Se me habia ido por alto el lugar donde tenia el codigo.

Comment: Mil Gracias amigo...

Comment: Si te fue util marca la respuesta +1 @V.Rocha

Answer (score 8):

```js
function guardar(){
   
    var _nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
    var _ape = document.getElementById("ape").value;
    var _ced = document.getElementById("ced").value;

    var fila="<tr><td>"+_nom+"</td><td>"+_ape +"</td><td>"+_ced +"</td></tr>";

    var btn = document.createElement("TR");
    btn.innerHTML=fila;
    document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
}
```

```css
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, td, th {
            border: 2px solid orange;
            padding:20px;
        }
        button{
            color:white;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:orange;
            width:100px;
            height:25px;
            font-size:15px;
        }
```

```html
 Nombre: <input id="nom" style="margin:10px" type="text"><br><br>
        Apellido:<input id="ape" style="margin:4px" type="text"><br><br>
        Cedula: <input id="ced" style="margin:20px" type="text"><br><br>
        <button id="btn_guardar" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button><br><br>

        <table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Cedula</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Debes trabajar con el método CreateElement();

Comment: Muchas gracias...pero si deseo que la funcion este en js como le llamo desde html

Comment: solo pones la función guardar en tu html entre las etiquetas <script>

Comment: Se le debe llamar desde la pagina.html al js

Comment: script src="insertar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: asi es tambien es una opcion poner la funcion en el archivo insertar.js

Comment: Asi lo hice pero no se registran los datos en la tabla si le pongo en el archivo js y en el primer caso poniendo dentro de la etiqueta scrip no se elimina